# Comparability Issue rails 4 beta, ruby 2.0.0, mongoid

Tags: mongoid3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I am creating a test application using following versions of rails, ruby and mongoid.

```
rails 4 beta
ruby 2.0.0
mongoid 3.1.2
```

My `GemFile` looks like this

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.beta1'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

But when i run `bundle` on console I get following error.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    mongoid (~> 3.1.2) ruby depends on
      activemodel (~> 3.2) ruby

    rails (= 4.0.0.beta1) ruby depends on
      activemodel (4.0.0.beta1)
```

Can anyone help? Please.....

Answer (score 73):

Use mongoid master from github, that has support for rails 4.0.

```
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'
```

Comment: fyi you can also specify github repos in your gemfile as `gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'`

Comment: Hopefully, mongoid releases the support for rails 4 soon