# Could not find generator mongoid:config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubymine

I have the following error when i try to rails generate mongoid:config 
Could not find generator mongoid:config. If i specify gem 'mongoid', '3.1.4', it gives me the following:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":   In
>   Gemfile:
>       mongoid (= 3.1.4) x86-mingw32 depends on
>         activemodel (~> 3.2) x86-mingw32
>
> ```
> rails (= 4.0.0.rc2) x86-mingw32 depends on
>   activemodel (4.0.0.rc2)
> ```

Please help. Thank you!

GemFile:
    gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc2'

```
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'mongoid-paperclip'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

GemFile.lock

```
GEM

  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.0.rc2)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (4.0.0.rc2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.0.rc2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.0.rc2)
      activemodel (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.0.rc2)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    arel (4.0.0)
    atomic (1.1.9)
    bson (1.9.0)
    bson_ext (1.9.0)
      bson (~> 1.9.0)
    builder (3.1.4)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.1)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0.beta, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
    durran-validatable (2.0.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    jbuilder (1.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2.0)
    jquery-rails (3.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    leshill-will_paginate (2.3.11)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.23)
    minitest (4.7.4)
    mongo (1.9.0)
      bson (~> 1.9.0)
    mongoid (1.0.6)
      activesupport (>= 2.2.2)
      durran-validatable (>= 2.0.1)
      leshill-will_paginate (>= 2.3.11)
      mongo (>= 0.18.2)
    mongoid-paperclip (0.0.8)
      paperclip (>= 2.3.6)
    multi_json (1.7.7)
    paperclip (3.4.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.0)
      mime-types
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.0.rc2)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      activerecord (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    railties (4.0.0.rc2)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0.rc2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.4)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.9)
    sass-rails (4.0.0.rc2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0.beta, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    sprockets (2.10.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.0)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.14)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (1.2.0)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.1.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  bson_ext
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  jbuilder (~> 1.2)
  jquery-rails
  mongoid
  mongoid-paperclip
  rails (= 4.0.0.rc2)
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.0.rc2)
  sdoc
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512683/comparability-issue-rails-4-beta-ruby-2-0-0-mongoid

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Rails 4 you need Mongoid 4, since this version is not yet officially released you could use the master branch from github. Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4.0.0.rc1', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
```

Then run
    bundle install

After that ran successfully you can use

```
 rails g mongoid:config
```

to generate a config file.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'

gem 'bson_ext'
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the bson gem is no longer required.  Here's what solved the issue for me.

Remove `gem 'bson_ext'`  from your Gemfile

You will have also have to rebundle 
`bundle install`

Than you should be able to run the config

Hope that helps.

Comment: No idea why, but removing bson_ext fixed the issue for me.